# Setting up Home Computer as File Server Windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, file-sharing, file-server

Here's my situation.

My brother has a PC with a large hard drive (2TB) in his bedroom. All our movies are stored on that drive.

I have another laptop hooked up to my telly in the sitting room, where I want to play those movies.

My brothers PC is left on 95% of the time so that's not an issue.

I want to access all these movie files (not using media streaming software, I want direct access to the folder).

I have a workgroup set up at the moment, which is doing an ok job. However it constantly disconnects and we're always having to restart our machines, it gets annoying.

Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but what would you suggest is the best way configure a good file sharing system.

Remember, my brother's PC is not to be used as just a server, it is used for general purpose use as well.

Both my brother's PC and my Laptop are running Windows 10.

The Laptop uses ethernet, the PC uses wifi with a usb adapter (Atheros chipset), The Router is ~ 8 metres from PC, and is a ZyXel F1000 model.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: How is your network set up, is it ethernet or wireless, if wireless how far are all the PC's from the router? What kind of wireless router? We need you entire configuration to help you.

Comment: Laptop uses ethernet, PC uses wifi with usb adapter (Atheros chipset), Router is ~8m from PC, Router is ZyXel F1000

Comment: Edit your question and add this new information please.

Comment: Is that ok, any ideas?

Comment: So all you are doing is sharing a folder on your brothers pc? When you say disconnect what do you mean?

Comment: When I try to open his PC on the network, I just get an error, a few minutes later, it will work. I know

Comment: what error, you need to be specific when posting information, add anything new to your question above, the more details about everything, the better chance someone can help.